# How to test a zend expressive rest api controller using PHPUnit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework, phpunit, mezzio

I'm trying to learn PHPUnit by testing a rest api controller built using zend expressive, but couldn't find any resources online regarding how to perform the same. The code in [Official documentation for zend framework](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-test/phpunit/) is not working for zend expressive. So I have tried following [PHPUnit documentation](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Here's what I have done as of now:-

```
use App1\Api\AccountApi;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use PHPUnit\DbUnit\TestCaseTrait;

class AccountTest extends TestCase {
    use TestCaseTrait;
    static private $pdo = null;

    private $conn = null;

    public function setUp(){
       /* Avoiding truncate operation of getDataSet() since we are trying to access view and not a table from database. */
    }


    public function getConnection() {
        if ($this->conn === null) {
            if (self::$pdo == null) {
                self::$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=workflow','root', 'root');
            }
            $this->conn = $this->createDefaultDBConnection(self::$pdo, ':host=localhost;dbname=workflow');
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }

    public function getDataSet()
    {
        $dataset = $this->getConnection()->createDataSet();
        return $dataset;
    }

    public function testIndexAction()
    {
        $api = new AccountApi();
        $response = $api->indexAction();  // Invokes a findAll() operation in the model which basically does a 'select * from workflow.account'
        print $response; // to see if a response is returning
    }
}
```

But when i run the above code, it throws this error:

```
1) AgentTest::testIndexAction
Zend\Db\Adapter\Exception\RuntimeException: Connect Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is k
nown.

C:\webserver\GIT\gco3api\vendor\zendframework\zend-db\src\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection.php:283
C:\webserver\GIT\gco3api\vendor\zendframework\zend-db\src\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Pdo.php:255
C:\webserver\GIT\gco3api\vendor\zendframework\zend-db\src\Sql\Sql.php:138
C:\webserver\GIT\gco3api\src\Core\src\Abstracts\Model.php:453
C:\webserver\GIT\gco3api\src\Core\src\Abstracts\Model.php:422
C:\webserver\GIT\gco3api\src\App1\src\Api\AccountApi.php:28
C:\webserver\GIT\gco3api\test\AppTest\App1\AccountTest.php:52
```

I really don't know if my approach for testing rest api controllers using PHPUnit is correct, since I'm new to php and phpunit. I'd appreciate any help in pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: well.. it's database connection error. Does page works on browser? If it's you have problem to configure freamwrok. did you check this page? http://zendframework.github.io/zend-test/phpunit/#unit-testing-with-phpunit?

Comment: @MehmetSÖĞÜNMEZ If I do this in the getDataSet() method it is displaying the tables. `$dataset = $this->getConnection()->createDataSet()->getTable('account_view'); print $dataset;`  Also as I have mentioned, the code in the documentation is not working. It can't find Zend\Test module.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, your connection works but `\Zend\Db\Adapter` don't know how to connect db. `Sql` object requires an `Adapter` so i guess you're doing something like that in your `Model.php` on line 453:

```
$sql = new Sql($container->get('Adapter');
```

So your adapter factory works and checks for config for db-connection. But you didn't initialize freamwork. You didn't read your config, your modules didn't send their config. Because you just created your controller with `new` keyword.

It's not freamwork running atm, it's just phpunit. That's why `Adapter` couldn't find database. You have to set-up freamwork.

You could set adapter via `__construct` method if you wrote your code on `Dependency Injection` pattern. That's one of reaseons we're following `SOLID` principles: `Testable Code`. But seems like you are accessing your adapter via abstraction. So you have to set up freamwork to test that action.

This's what i understood from your code. If anything is wrong, please let me know.